# running out of memory trying to add column (np.concatenate) to numpy array, due to duplication of data

Tags: python, numpy

I have this little function that adds a column to any dimension of a multidimensional ndarray (maybe more accurate to say increases the dimension on any axis).

```
def add_column(A, count=1, append=True, axis=-1):
    '''add extra column(s) to i'th dimension of ndarray A'''
    s = list(A.shape)
    s[axis] = count
    Z = np.zeros(s, dtype=A.dtype.type)
    if append: B = np.concatenate([A,Z], axis=axis)
    else: B = np.concatenate([Z,A], axis=axis)
    return B
```

It works fine most of the time, however if A is very large, I run out of memory because the concatenate is duplicating the data (It's not that I don't have enough memory for the larger array, I don't have memory for the larger array AND the original array at the same time). Is there a way of growing an array without duplicating the data? It's almost like what I need to do is dump A to disk, create a new array B which has the extra column, and then read A into B. This would be very slow though. Is there another way?

Comment: Maybe the solution is asking yourself why do you need to add zeros in the first place. Maybe you can formulate the following operations differently so you don't need to allocate this much memory.

Comment: i do need the extra column

Comment: There's little you can do with an array this big, Many operations on or with an array produce a copy, if only temporary.

Comment: `np,resize` can grow an array.  But data buffer has to be contiguous.  And it has its own rules for filling the new space.